# Javascript Add Item in Array to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, netsuite, openair

I am trying to make a multiline string from taking an array of user ids and matching them to the username and then printing the string.

This is what I have so far and am wondering what the proper way to do this would be:

```
var names;
for(var i in array) {
    var obj = new NSOA.record.oaUser(i);
    var username = obj.name;
    names = names + username;
}
```

Ideally names would be a string that looks like:

"Smith, Bob, Doe, Jane, Miller, Larry"

Any help you can give would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You can use the native `.join` method to combine items in an array.

Comment: It is not clear, please elaborate, what are the inputs and what is the expected result

Comment: Why are there line separators in the string? Doesn't it make more sense to maintain an array of these names if you want to output them on separate lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're printing to HTML insert a `<br>` after each array element in the string:

```
var names = '';
for(var i in array) {
    var obj = new NSOA.record.oaUser(i);
    var username = obj.name;
    names = names + username + '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) all the name in an array then finally [Join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) it by any separator.

For example:

```js
var arr = [];

arr.push('Smith');
arr.push('Bob');
arr.push('Doe');
arr.push('Jane');
arr.push('Miller');
arr.push('Larry');

document.write(arr.join(', '));
```